# Multiple radio button groups, check if 'checked' has changed

Tags: javascript, html, button, radio-button

Hi I have 2 radio button groups. I'm trying to accomplish that whenever you check either a different radio button from the first group or the second, that it triggers a fetch request.

```js
let subscriptionType = document.querySelector('.membership-type-radio:checked').value;
let duration = document.querySelector('.duration-radio:checked').value;
```

```css
.duration-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.duration-box .btn-label {
    flex-basis: 32%;
}

.btn-label {
    border: 2px solid var(--purple);
    color: var(--purple);
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.btn-label:hover {
    background-color: var(--purple);
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.membership {
    color: red;
}

.membership-options-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.membership-options-container .btn-label {
    flex-basis: 49%;
}

.membership-type-radio, .duration-radio {
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

.membership-type-radio[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-label,
.duration-radio[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-label {
    background-color: var(--purple);
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="step">
                <h2 class="step-title">Abonnement</h2>
                <div class="membership-options-container">
                    <input type="radio" name="subscriptionType" value="daluren" class="membership-type-radio" id="daluren" checked />
                    <label for="daluren" class="btn-label">Daluren</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="subscriptionType" value="Premium" class="membership-type-radio" id="premium" />
                    <label for="premium" class="btn-label">Premium</label>
                </div>

                <div class="memberships-container">
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <h2 class="step-title">Looptijd</h2>
                <div class="duration-box">
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="104" class="duration-radio" id="104" checked />
                    <label for="104" class="btn-label">104 Weken</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="52" class="duration-radio" id="52" />
                    <label for="52" class="btn-label">52 Weken</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="4" class="duration-radio" id="4" />
                    <label for="4" class="btn-label">4 Weken</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When the page loads, I get the values of the pre-selected radio buttons, but I also want to update those values of the variables as soon as they change. I already tried events like this:

```
    let subscriptionTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.membership-type-radio');
subscriptionTypes?.forEach((type) => {
    type.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        subscriptionType = e.target.value;
        console.log(subscriptionType);
    });
});
```

The above code does change the variable, but I'm looking for a solution that is re-usable for multiple fields.

I also tried this, which does print the variables, but does not update them:

```
let subscriptionType = document.querySelector('.membership-type-radio:checked').value;
let duration = document.querySelector('.duration-radio:checked').value; 
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.membership-type-radio, .duration-radio');
inputs?.forEach((type) => {
    type.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        window[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        console.log(subscriptionType, duration);
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you already tried to achieve this? Please [share](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73852146/edit) that particular [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us

Comment: @shaedrich modified my question, now it includes what I've tried.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can dynamically fill your variables:

```js
a = null;
b = null;
c = null;
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        window[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        console.log(a, b, c);
    });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="a">
  <input name="b">
  <input name="c">
</form>
```

Comment: wbat does window[e.target.name] do?

Comment: It sets the input's `value` to a variable in the window scope (which is the default) with the input's `name`. So for the first input, it would be equivalent to `a = e.target.value`

Comment: I tried this ```let subscriptionType = document.querySelector('.membership-type-radio:checked').value;
let duration = document.querySelector('.duration-radio:checked').value;

let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.membership-type-radio, .duration-radio');

inputs?.forEach((type) => {
    type.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        window[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        console.log(subscriptionType, duration);
    });
});``` It does print the variables, but it's not updating their values

Comment: Could you [add that to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73852146/edit) below "**EDIT**" or the like?

Comment: You could simplify `let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.membership-type-radio, .duration-radio'); ` to `let inputs = [ subscriptionType, duration ]`

Comment: simplifying that does not work for me.

Comment: Apparently it does not work work, since I first set those variable names already with a value

Comment: Got it working now! in case I need to use this kind of logic in the future, how do I look this way up?

Comment: I'm glad, you could get it to work! What are you intending to look up?

Comment: This way of working what you explained to me, I've never seen solutions like that before, but they seem interesting

Comment: Frankly, I don't know a good website where this is "taught" 